# Can we instantiate Java Objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, pojo, dwr

I know we can do this via `DWR library` to work with Java objects in Javascript.
But I would like to know if we can actually instantiate `Java Objects` in `Javascript`, using plain Javascript objects?

I searched on the internet and found [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/LiveConnect_Overview) and [this link](http://www.nusphere.com/kb/jscoreref/packages.html) which speaks about `Packages object` in Javascript. I even read that this object is a part of JS since JS 1.1, is that true?

But when I actually used `var myClass = new Packages.myPackage.myClass();` , it says, `Packages` is not defined, obviously I am missing out something here.

For my use case I have to instantiate a `Java Pojo` in JS.
Any clue folks on how to achieve this?

Comment: No, Java and JavaScript are two very different things, despite the similar names.

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet!

Comment: Yep, I know those two are different entities. I've been working with them since many years now. But, it just happened to by my use case, so I was wondering if there is any work around for this case!

Comment: No, as you have mentioned yourself, you are gonna need something like DWR or GWT, etc.

Comment: You could create the serialised form of the Java object. When you deserialise it the JVM won't care where it was created.

Comment: How do we create that in Javascript? If I am just trying to instantiate my class, rather just how to even access the class to instantiate / serialize, is the primary question.

Answer (score 1):

This feature depends on the JavaScript engine (i.e. the interpreter which runs the JavaScript). I haven't tried to do this in a browser but it might be possible when the Java plugin is enabled (which you shouldn't do for security reasons, at least not unconditionally).

The special object `Packages` is a feature of the [Rhino engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino), for example, which is a JavaScript interpreter that runs in a Java VM. The `Packages` has overloaded the accessor methods so when you write `Packages.com.pany.Foo`, it will internally look up the class and return something that wired the Java and the JavaScript worlds in a useful way.

You can find a tutorial here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Java object and assign it to a variable in JavaScript with the help of the new
    keyword. When you create an instance of a Java class, JavaScript automatically creates a JavaObject
    object. For example, you can instantiate a Java String from JavaScript and assign it to a variable. 
    Then you can use the dot operator to access the object’s `length()`

```
var myString=new java.lang.String("Test String");
alert(myString.length()); //prints 11
```

You can follow this link for more information http://www.sitepoint.com/connect-java-to-javascript-with-liveconnect/